# Using CURL to POST to a php file to login to my website doesn't set the cookies/session

Tags: php, forms, post, cookies, curl

i am using the following php script to login to my website,as you can see the script post to another php file with login parameters and the other php file handles all connection(it register the cookies , session , etc..) I checked and the login php file succuessfuly get the post values from the first php file but doesn't register the cookies nor the session. i can login with Ajax.post with no problems.

php file number 1 -

```
<?php
$url = "http://myurl.org.il/login_exec.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=yarden&password=yarden");
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
?>
```

the part that handles the cookies and session registration in php file number 2 -

```
session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            $cookie_auth = rand_string(10) . $member['username'];
         $auth_key = $cookie_auth;
         $auth_query = mysql_query("UPDATE member SET auth_key = '" . $auth_key . "' WHERE username = '" . $member['username'] . "'");
         setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/", "myurl.org.il", false, true);
```

So for short - Php file number 1 post to php file number 2 the login values, php file number 2 gets the post values but doesn't register the cookies nor the session..
and again - i can succuessfully post to php file number 2 with ajax and it will register the cookies.
i tryed to search around google and stackoverflow but i'm kind of lost beacause theres so many answers that i tried with no success.
Thank you all ! :)

Comment: CURL is a communication between one server and another server so the server being POSTed to has no idea about the existence of the browser.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! any idea what i can do to solve that?

Comment: May I ask why you are CURLing to your own script? This seems like you can greatly simplify the design in many ways. Are these scripts on separate domains? Starting a `Session` on an http site will be lost if you switch to https by the way

Comment: Its the same domain.
I have a wordpress system on my site and i have my main site(not wordpress). I'm trying to login to my main site through the wordpress login( so when a user logs in to the wordpress system it will also log him in to the main site) im not worried about not matching user information between the wordpress to the main site as my wordpress system will register to the main site database when you register on the wordpress system
so bottomline - when a user login to my wordpress system it will also run the curl script in my main post above.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never worked with WordPress before so I cannot comment on best practices. Can you start the session before the CURL and post the `session_id()` to the next script and have the next script assume the ID of the previous session? `session_id($previous_id)`

Comment: I tried what you said and it didn't work. Even if it would, what about the cookies? I'm trying to find a workaround for my problem, but i can't seem to find one. i really appreciate your help!